# Creating loading animation on button click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a form created using ruby on rails. When i click on create, I want a round progress bar to show up until the same page is rendered again.

My form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(:contact, :url => {:action => :create}) do |f| %>
    <div id="contacts">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="info_type">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Full Name :</th>
            <td><input id="contact_full_name" type="text" name="contact[full_name]" onblur="validate_full_name()"></input></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><label id="lname"><span style="color:#842222">*Enter a name.</span></label></td>
          </tr>
         </table>
         <div id="button_create_display">
            <input type="submit" id="create" value="Create" name="commit" onclick="return validate()"></input> 

         </div>
  <% end %>
```

Please help me!

Comment: And what does the code posted have to do with jQuery, and what have you tried to create such a progress bar ?

Comment: Progress bar means that you will need some sort of logic to increment it.  If you just want a loading animation gif/CSS then you should update your question.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb yes i want an animation/gif to show till the page is rendered again. please help.. I dont knw how to proceed.

Comment: Whats the use of showing us the form?